# Exclude samples from dokka documentation

Tags: sample, kotlin-dokka

I pointed the dokka samples directory to my test sources so I could refer test methods with `@sample` in my documentation and have examples that are tested. This works, except now dokka generates documentation for my tests as well, which is obviously not what I want.

Is there a way to avoid that? I want no trace of my samples or tests in my documentation other than the bits I refer with `@sample`.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried excluding the tests with `perPackageOption`s?

Answer (score 1):

I have had a similar problem with dokkaHtml. The example from [here](https://github.com/Kotlin/dokka/blob/39cceaa3af6df5c419b9cd1f3d880ac8cf7d94a5/integration-tests/gradle/projects/it-basic/build.gradle.kts) help me. I use:

```
dokkaSourceSets {
    configureEach {
        suppressedFiles.from(file("src/main/kotlin/it/suppressedByPath"))
```